# How to parse "As for the philosophical content explicitly picks over in the film’s dialogue"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, parsing

I can't parse the first clause of this sentence.

> **As for the philosophical content explicitly picks over in the film’s dialogue**, it’s something for the viewer to digest, but it all seems a little leadenly expressed—and perhaps loses something in translation (the payoff lines about Misumi being a “vessel”). ([source](https://www.filmcomment.com/blog/film-week-third-murder/))

My understanding is that it should be a noun phrase that follows "as for", but it seems something is missing in the sentence. I am not sure what "pick over" means here. Does it mean either of [these](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pick-over)? If the phrase means "to examine a collection", it needs a subject and an object. What are its subject and object? Shouldn't the sentence be

> **As for the philosophical content *that the director* explicitly picks over in the film’s dialogue**, it’s something for the viewer to digest, but it all seems a little leadenly expressed—and perhaps loses something in translation (the payoff lines about Misumi being a “vessel”).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My understanding is that *picks* should be changed to *picked.*

> **As for the philosophical content explicitly picked over in the film’s dialogue,** it’s something for the viewer to digest.

Now it sounds normal.

Comment: That line immediately makes sense now.

Comment: That was going to be my answer. +1. And congratulations, OliGar, on spotting the error.